# Undetected Logitech MX 5500 Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, logitech, wireless-keyboards

I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit but I can't since Logitech MX 5500 Combo (Keyboard/Mouse) is not detected. I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi greapko, can you add what hardware you have and if you have already connected the bluetooth device to the PC.

Comment: Can you try to unplug and plug again the small usb stick provided with the keyboard/mouse? Then type dmesg in a terminal and give the 20 latest line.

Answer (score 6):

That is part of a bug had been around for a while. [Launchpad Bug 870227](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/870227).

The only fix for now for 12.10 is to have a separate keyboard (or boot in to an OS that can modify your installation) and go in to `/lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules` and comment out these lines:

```
# Logitech devices
#KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[34bc]", \
#RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```

Just put a `#` at the beginning like in the code above.

Answer (score 6):

This problem also occurs in 16.04 LTS.

The problem is that you can't enter the pin when trying to pair the keyboard/mouse in bluetooth settings.

Found this solution which works for my own MX 5500 Keyboard and mouse

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/872940

On 15.10 Wily Werewolf though, the path to the modified file is:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules
```

I modified line 14:

From:

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]",
```

To:

```
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]",
```

Thank you for sharing the solution :)

Comment: @ByteCommander: Sorry, that was accidental. I meant to make this comment on a different answer.

Comment: This worked for a MX 5000 keyboard using the included dongle too

Answer (score 0):

I would only like to add to the answers above since this is still a problem in  Ubuntu 18.04 (smh...the future seems bleak :P). But I have found a site where you could make this change permanent. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-does-one-change-a-system-udev-rule-permanently-4175453832/

> Put your modified 60-cdrom_id.rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d . That's
>   where local overrides go. From `man 7 udev`:
>
> > Quote: Rule files are
> >     required to have a unique name, duplicate file names are ignored.
> >     Files in /etc/udev/rules.d/ have precedence over files with the same
> >     name in /lib/udev/rules.d/. This can be used to ignore a default rules
> >     file if needed.

Hopefully I revived this thread for somebody's sake (hint hint hi future me :P)

Answer (score 0):

Its 2019 and this bug still exists. If you are worried it won't work, don't. It does still work and its ridiculously easy to fix. On Debian works just as fine. Just follow the basic instructions above. I will rewrite them just to reassure:

go to the file "/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules"

find this on line 14 (you will probably see it's under a set of comments about Logitech):

KERNEL=="hiddev*"

change it to:

KERNEL=="hidraw*"

don't touch the rest of the line or any other line.

Save the file. Reboot.

Done. You're welcome. And welcome to Linux malfunctioning hell. You will learn a lot of shit that should work by default while trying to learn stuff that actually matters. They say it pays. Find out for yourself.