# internal keyboard not working except power button

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I have ubuntu 18.04. The touchpad works an the power button works. I plugged an external keyboard and it works just fine

I have tried installing/reinstalling keyboard river but it didn't work

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all

sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

I have also followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237051/undetected-logitech-mx-5500-keyboard-and-mouse) but it didn't work

## UPDATES

so I honestly really don't know what's going on anymore. the keyboard doesn't work from windows nor the ubuntu liveUSB. I have gone to a professional to see it. they don't think it is a hardware problem because my asus keyboard has lights, and those lights work just fine. and according to them if it was a hardware problem the power button wouldn't work nor would the lights. I insisted on them to at least open and see and they did but found no problem in the hardware. I also opened it myself and tried to remove and insert the battery again with no results. The last thing i did was completely reformatting my laptop. it didn't work and the problem is still there :(

I just have no idea how this happened to begin with. I ran out of solutions from the internet. My last hope is one repair store that would take 3 weeks to look into the problem with very expensive fees -I have to pay 300$ just to open a request to fix it-

## Update 2

I fixed it!!!!! I went to BIOS and clicked reset default and now it is working :D

edit: nevermind after rebooting it went back to not working

## Update 3

I went to high-end fixing place, they changed the keyboard and it didn't work, they suggested replacing the motherboard, which costs the same as the actual laptop price so I refused. That's the end of my journey I guess, I will just use an external for a couple years until I finish studying then buy a better laptop once employed

Comment: does the keyboard work when you boot from a live USB?

Comment: I don't have access to one atm. but my laptop has both ubuntu and windows. the keyboard doesn't work in any of them. I am afraid it is a hardware problem as I have reinstalled the keyboard from windows too with no result :(

Comment: sounds like hardware... have you taken the laptop apart to ensure the ribbon cable is properly connected?

Comment: I have never opened up  a laptop before. Do you have any tutorials on doing this?

Comment: there should be many on youtube... search for your laptop model on youtube

Comment: thank you! will do

Comment: You bet. Good luck! Feel free to hit me up in a private chat if you have any questions during the disassembly :)